# Let $X$ be the number of heads showing, and let $Y$ be the number of tails showing. Compute $Cov(X, Y)$ and $Corr(X, Y)$.

Tags: probability, statistics, covariance, variance, expected-value

> Suppose you flip four fair coins. Let $X$ be the number of heads showing, and
>   let $Y$ be the number of tails showing. Compute $Cov(X, Y)$ and $Corr(X, Y)$.

Although it is not stated, it is clear that $X,Y$ are Binomial to $n=4, \theta=1/2$.

Thus we know that variance of a binom dist is $n\theta(1-\theta)=1$ in our case.

We also know that the expectation of a binom dist is $n\theta=2$ in our case.

Thus, our formula becomes:

$cov(X,Y)=E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)=E(XY)-(2)(2)$

> How do I calculate $E(X)E(Y)$?

Can I treat $X$ and $Y$ as independent?

Comment: I suspect that $X$ and $Y$ are binomial.  This may be what you intended

Comment: They are not independent note that $Y=4-X$.

Comment: Note that X and $X$ are regarded as *"different" symbols* sometimes. Mathematicians use different fonts of the same symbol all the time within the literature to mean different things. It is good practice, then, to stay consistent with one's notation throughout any given text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$E(X)=E(Y)=2$ as you computed.  $E(X^2)=E(Y^2)=5$, so $Var(X)=Var(Y)=1$ and    $E(XY)=E(X(4-X))=4E(X)-E(X^2)=3$, so $Cov(X,Y)=-1$ and $Cor(X,Y)=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I calculate $E(X)E(Y)$?

You just did.  You likely mean $E(XY)$.

> Can I treat $X$ and $Y$ as independent?

No, they are clearly *very* dependent, and indeed $Y=4-X$ is a *linear relation*, so you immediately know the correlation coefficent.

You might use $\mathsf E(XY)=\mathsf E(4X-X^2)$, so $\mathsf {Cov}(X,Y)=\mathsf E(4X-X^2)-\mathsf E(X)(\mathsf E(4-X)$

In short: $$\mathsf Cov(X,Y)~{=\mathsf Cov(X,4-X) \\= -\mathsf Var(X)}$$

And you know the variance of a binomially distributed random variable.

From this you can calculate the correlation coefficient, if feel the you need to.

Comment: If I define $Y=4-X$, then how can I calculate the variance of $Y$? It would be $var(4)-var(X)=0-1=-1$? How is this allowed.

Comment: @KSplitX - no.  The variance of $a+bX$ is $b^2$ times the variance of $X$.  Here $a=4$ and $b=-1$ so $b^2=1$ and the variance of $Y$ is equal to the  variance of $X$